# ASP.NET SQL Insert Error

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql, sql, sql-server

In ASP.NET, I'm trying to configure a DetailsView control with the insert statement.  I run the insert command and I get the error:

> "Column 'Address' cannot be null"

My SQL:

```
INSERT INTO Students (Name, Address,College_Status,Email,Fraternity_Status,Major,Pledge_Class,Ship_ID,Dues_Paid,Service_Hours,Money_Donated,Phone,Shirt_Size,Phone_Carrier,Birthday,Chair_Position,Ritual_Proficiency,Library_Hours)  Values (@Name,@Address,@College_Status,@Email,@Fraternity_Status,@Major,@Pledge_Class,@Ship_ID,@Dues_Paid,@Service_Hours,@Money_Donated,@Phone,@Shirt_Size,@Phone_Carrier,@Birthday,@Chair_Position,@Ritual_Proficiency,@Library_Hours)
```

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I think it's just a simple SQL syntax error.
Thanks

Comment: post the parameters also

Comment: The issue seems to be that the control just cannot accept a blank value in any textbox here.  I guess I will try to use a try/catch block.

Comment: Please post your SQL table attributes with its datatype

Comment: Thanks, but the logic below fully answered the question.  I appreciate your willingness to help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear that you are not entering all of the columns for the Students table. Try doing

```
INSERT INTO Students (*column names*) VALUES (*values*)
```

This will make sure that your query works even if you add a new column as well as help you with a quick sanity check to ensure that you have all of the columns required.

EDIT:

Based on your new results, I see the problem. Your SQL is wrong. It should be something like this:

INSERT INTO Students (Name) VALUES (@Name)

You shouldn't be using the column name = parameter name in the value section.

EDIT 2:

For the "Address cannot be null error", you need to check the value you are inserting into Address. It is a non-nullable field in the database and the value you are entering is null. This should have you return an error to the user saying they need an address.

Comment: I have updated the columns.  The new error spits out:  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`,`Ritual_Proficiency`,`Library_Hours`)  Values (`Name`=@Name,`Address`=@Address' at line 1 "

Comment: @Klinetel Is there a reason you are using backticks instead of single quotes? I don't ever recall seeing that while doing SQL

Comment: Not anymore, I originally used them for columns with spaces in between (two words).

Comment: It probably shouldn't make a difference though.

Comment: @Klinetel It doesn't, that was my fault. Check my edit for what is wrong with your query.

Comment: One moment, I will go through each one now.

Comment: I now get the error:  "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`,`Ritual_Proficiency`,`Library_Hours`)  Values (@Name,@Address,@College_Status,' at line 1 "  I updated my SQL above.

Comment: I took out the quotes altogether.  Now it says "Address cannot be null".

Comment: @Klinetel I have updated my answer based on your newest edit.

Answer (score 1):

The syntax you have written  for insert looks strange to me.

It should be,

```
Insert into table_name (col1, col2) values (@val_col1, @val_col2)
```

Comment: This is for MySQL.  Please look above at my edited columns.  Should I just use the @values instead of each column name =@something?

Answer (score 1):

seems kinda simple. are you still stuck ?  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/47ed30/1